# How to achieve this sticking out image layout without using negative margins?

Tags: html, css

This is the layout image:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the images of the phones are sticking out of the blue container.

I have tried several things, such as:

I tried to use a grid with 5 rows where a `<div>` tag expanded all the rows and was set to have its background as the phone images. Then I set the blue background box to use only the rows form 2-4.

This somehow did the trick, but when the browser window was resized the image started to shrink and be positioned in a funky way.

As a newcomer to CSS I want to avoid negative margins because I have read they are "evil".

Is there any way to accomplish this in a clean/non-hacky way?

Comment: You can use `transform: translateY(-100px)` to move the images where they need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `transform` property to move the images where they need to be.

You'll need to build your layout as usual, but without the images being raised/lowered outside their default position.

Once you've done that, you can use `transform: translateY(-100px)` to raise or lower the images into their target position.

A quick example of this can be shown using `<div>` tags:

```css
/* Setup some basic layouts to mimic the layout required */
.container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.banner {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.image-1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-50px); /* move the image up */
}
.image-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(50px); /* move the image down */
}
.example-filler {
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
      <div class="image-1"></div>
      <div class="image-2"></div>
      <div class="example-filler">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan't to use negative margins (which are fine in this situation). You can try to give these styles to your image.

```
img {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

You can learn [more about the "position" property here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).
It is very important for beginners to understand how it works.

Comment: `position: responsive` isn't valid CSS.

Comment: @KirkBeard oh, sorry. I'm tired :) 
position: relative;

Comment: hah, no worries, but it did prompt me quick check the documentation just to make sure I hadn't missed out on some new feature.